# touchesBegan in custom UITableViewCell, touchesEnded in UIView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, touchesbegan

I am trying to mimic a drag n drop of an image from a `UITableView` to a `UIView`. Both the UITableView and UIView are on the same view, side by side.

**My approach:**

is to fire the `touchesBegan` event inside the `UITableView` (i.e. when a cell is touched/selected) and fire the touchesEnded event when the touch ends in the `UIView`.

**The problem:**

So I created a custom `UITableViewCell` that contains a `UIImageView` and a couple of `UILabels`. And I set the `User Interaction Enabled` for this `UIImageView`. Then to receive the `touchesBegan` event, I did override the `touchesBegan` method inside the custom `UITableViewCell` class; and now I am able to receive the `touchesBegan` event from the cell.

**The problem is**

I am not getting the `touchesEnded` event when the touch ends on the `UIView`. Note that I already implemented the `touchesEnded` method inside the view controller class (not in the custom class); and if I start and stop a touch within this `UIView`, I see the `touchesEnded` being fired.

Is there anything I am missing here?

Using Xcode 4.6 (4H127), testing on iPad 2 with iOS 6.1.3

Answer (score 0):

This will not work that way. You will need to utilize the touch methods on the parent view that contains both of your subviews. Could look abstractly like this:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    if ([self touchOnCell:touches]) { //check to see if your touch is in the table
        isDragging = YES;             //view cell
    }
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    //do your dragging code here
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    if (isDragging && [self touchOnDropView:touches]) {
        //do your drop code here 
    }
}
```

now if this doesnt work like that alone you might want to implement the `hitTest` on the tableView and if the touch is in the dragging object's region, then return the parent view.

hope this helps